# How to deal with the keys/password used for backing up files?

Tags: backup, encryption, password-management

Basically I am trying to figure out how to keep my backup secure, I am going to be archiving the home directory of my system which has some important documents such as tax returns, a password database, etc...

So the best way to keep that secure would be to use a key file that would enable it to be encrypted before backing up without the weakness of a "short/semi long" password, it could even be combined with a password for extra security.

However my biggest worry is.... You can't backup the key file with the backup because then you are basically storing the key with the lock which makes no sense.  I mean sure you could encrypt the key file with a password but then the password becomes the weakest line of defense.

So at this point in time I am wondering what is the best way to keep the key file secure *and* backed up somehow so a loss of the computer or the house burning down won't compromise my ability to go back and retrieve my encrypted backups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what it's worth to you, USB stick in a small safe deposit box at your local bank?

Comment: That could work, but one thing is... aren't the flash memories all mostly made up of "charge" in cells so those overtime would rundown, so I suppose you could back that up also with several sheets of paper with the key printed out on it?

Comment: The first is a non-issue if you don't plan on leaving it there unchecked for many many years (even then I don't think it's an issue). Although I'm by no means a hardware expert, I don't believe SSD drives suffers more from degradation than does "normal" drives.

For printing the key, I can't take you seriously.

Comment: On printing the key, the id_rsa.pub is about 378 character long, and the id_rsa is about 1700 character long so its possible to print it out.  Yes the printing is like a "final resort" kind of thing.  Using a USB stick with the key and the password manager information on it would be acceptable so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use a password manager program that keeps your passwords in a strongly encrypted file, you can store the key in there.  I use keypass since it is open source.  If you use a "strong" master password for that password manager, you can then post the file somewhere you can get it later.

I use Mozy with my own private key for backup and I store my password manager data file on my webserver (hosted elsewhere).

If you have a gmail account you can also email the password manager data file to yourself and let google "back it up" for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I do have a password manager, it would be a good location to manage all of the keys and certificates in it and including it on the USB stick and storing it in a security deposit box would work.  Thanks :)